# does call with current continuation ignore its own continuation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, continuations

I'm trying to understand continuation passing and Call-with-current-continuation.
As per this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Continuation_monad
the call with CC method is implemented as follows:

```
call_cc :: ((a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
call_cc f k = f (\t x -> k t) k
```

As described by this [signature](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1f91b06cd2e724f17fe38269afbbb786a24e6d12) and [implementation](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/51e12a6846142aa27cb1277b8a7e4412f2590322).

However, we can see that the `x` parameter is here never used.
Does it mean that any continuation passed to `f` is always ignored that the initial continuation `k` is always replacing it?
In that case, does it mean that `call-with-cc` can only ever call a function with that is one-level deep and not more? (because the next function that would be called in a normal control flow with a continuation `x` is ignored)

In that case it seems very limiting, what is its practical use?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Continuation_monad) you can find more readable definition of `callCC` with very specific explanation:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadCont m where 
    callCC :: ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> m a
```

> The MonadCont class provides the callCC function, which provides an
>   escape continuation mechanism for use with Continuation monads. Escape
>   continuations allow you to abort the current computation and return a
>   value immediately. They achieve a similar effect to throwError and
>   catchError within an Error monad.

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style#callCC) you can see some pretty examples how to use it.

But in general: `callCC` does not ignore input, but it enhances your procedure with way to do it.

You are defining some function like

```
doSomething panicExit = do
  ...
  when failCondition $ panicExit inputToStartOver
  ...
```

And then converting to normal continuation via `callCC doSomething`

And exactly this `panicExit` input-ignoring throw-like has caught your eye. You procedure is not obliged to fail to default value, but you can do it when you like.

Comment: thanks!
in that example : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style#Deciding_when_to_use_k
does it mean that calling k will return to the previous contiunation (the current one) and that "return (show $ y - 4)" will display y-4 and end the program?

Comment: @lezebulon Calling `k` in `callC`ed `do` block will completely ignore all actions after this call. So `return (show $ y - 4)` will be done only if `y > 20`  condition is `False`

Comment: yes but what would return do when called? is it the same as k ?

Answer (score 1):

(For the sake of exposition, let me use more concise syntax rather than real Haskell.)

`callcc f` applies the given function `f` to the current continuation `k`.  *If this continuation `k` is ever invoked under another continuation `x`, the latter continuation `x` is indeed discarded*.

For instance, in `1 + callcc (\k -> 2 + (k 3))`, the variable `k` is bound to the outer continuation `1 + []` where `[]` is a *hole* into which a return value shall be filled.  When this `k` is applied as in `(k 3)`, *the inner continuation `1 + (2 + [])` is discarded*.  As a result, the entire expression becomes `1 + 3` and evaluates to `4`.

On the other hand, in `1 + callcc (\k -> 2 + 4)`, the continuation `k` is never invoked and the whole expression yields `1 + (2 + 4)`, that is, `7`.

By combining the two examples above, you can do more complicated things like `1 + callcc (\k -> 2 + (if some_complex_condition then (k 3) else 4))`, which gives `1 + 3` if `some_complex_condition` is `true`, or `1 + (2 + 4)` otherwise.

To sum up and answer your question:

> However, we can see that the x parameter is here never used.

`x` is discarded *if the continuation `k` is invoked*; however, when `k` is *not* invoked, `x` is applied to the "normal" return value, as in the examples above.  (The latter case corresponds to the `return` operation in the continuation monad.)

P.S.

Above I adopted a direct, non-monadic syntax for brevity.  Using the continuation monad in Haskell, the following example

```
callCC (\k -> do r <- (k 3); return (2 + r))
```

invokes the outer continuation `k` *discarding the inner `2 + []`* and returns `3`, while

```
callCC (\k -> do r <- (return 4); return (2 + r))
```

gives `2 + 4`.

Comment: wouldn't that be (if some_complex_condition then (k 3) else *return* 4) ?

Comment: That's where I used "more concise syntax rather than real Haskell".  The "real Haskell" code for `1 + callcc (\k -> 2 + (if some_complex_condition then (k 3) else 4))` would be `do a <- callCC $ \k -> (do b <- if some_complex_condition then k 3 else return 4; return $ 2 + b); return $ 1 + a`.  The continuation monad in Haskell requires different syntax (and typing) for expressions that may invoke a continuation...

Comment: I added a postscript using continuation monad in Haskell.